# How is it possible to test a public facing FTP server from within that network?

Tags: ftp

I've setup a public facing FTP server on a FIOS based connection, and would like to be able to test it. I can't find a good way to test it while being on the same network.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you test it??

Comment: what exactly do you want to test?  Your firewall (NAT, DMZ, etc.) configuration, or the FTP server itself?  If it's the latter, you don't need to be outside; if it's the former, you either have to _get_ outside somehow (VPN, etc.) or see if your firewall supports NAT reflection.

Comment: How would one configure NAT reflection properly? Would be a good answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to it locally (via the server's inside IP), but to be sure it's really working you'll need an outside location to test from. Among other things, you need to make sure that something upstream isn't blocking you accidentally.

I'd look into outside VPN services - there are a number of companies that offer VPNs that you connect to. You could connect to the VPN, then through the VPN connect to your server. That will be an outside connection, and allow you test fully without having to leave your chair.

I've never used one of those services, but a quick Google search turned up a lot of them, so this shouldn't be too hard to find one of reasonable price.

Answer (score 0):

Besides connecting to the FTP's internal IP, no. You will need to be on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use remote tools such as logmein to control computer at your house for example and try connecting to the FTP server that you created. You obviously would need to worry about the required ports to open.